# How do I prettify a value after user input with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I want to find a consistent way to custom prettify some input values after user input. (The underlying model has to change together with the value.)

What is the best practice in Angularjs? `$watch`, `ng-change`, doing a `prettified="myFormatterFunction"` directive or sth else?

Comment: You are probably looking for the `$parsers` and `$formatters` of `ng-model`, see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: How can I use them in this case? Inside a directive?

Comment: Yes, you need a directive. It will `require` the `ngModel` use the `$parsers`/`$formatters`.